# I am using EgisTec ES603 Swipe Fingerprint Sensor, When The windows wake up from sleep it doesn't work, What can I do to make it always awake?

Tags: swipe, sleep, sensors, fingerprint, biometrics

Hi I'm using biometric device ( EgisTec ES603 ), 
When the windows wakes up from sleep it doesn't work ( It works just when I unplug and plug it from the USB.
In Device manager I am seeing EgisTec ES603 Swipe Fingerprint Sensor,
In it's properties I don't see Power Management to make it don't go to sleep when the computer goes to sleep.
What can I do to make the biometric device always awake ?
I appreciate any help
Thanks.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  You should mention that in an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow the same procedure as you might to make your mouse wake the computer.:

Click Start, type "Control Panel", look under Devices and Printers.  If your device shows up, double-click it, click the Hardware tab, click Properties, click Change Settings, Click Power Management, and set the checkbox "Allow this device to wake the computer."

If your device doesn't show up or doesn't present the same dialogs, I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but when I double-click the device in Devices and Printers and click hardware tab then properties and then change settings there is no Power Management, it shows me the same thing like when I choose Properties in Device Manager

Comment: If that's the case I suspect your device doesn't present a power management interface to Windows, and if not, it probably cannot be set to wake Windows.  Some HID parts offer this -- mice for example -- and some might not.  Only other thing I might suggest is to update the drivers as suggested on this Microsoft forum [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/fingerprint-sensor-not-working-after-laptop/42b70dcf-f32b-46c1-97ce-838edea8574a)